# Center Horizontal doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, center, android-xml

I'm trying to set the position of imagebutton in center, but it doesn't work.

Now when I try to set it to center it goes nearly to right.

Can someone show me where I've made a mistake in my codes?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EBEBEB" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#EBEBEB" >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagefield"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagefield"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="imagebutton1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagefield"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />   
        <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/imagebutton1"/> 



</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: maybe it is because of Your layout_alignBottom attribute which is et to the imageView..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No its not because of it.

Comment: Could you describe where you want the ImageView to be with regard to the ImageButton?

Comment: I want the ImageButton to be in bottm,center of ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COPY PASTE BELOW CODE

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EBEBEB" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#EBEBEB" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagefield"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_chat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="imagebutton1" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imagefield"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagefield"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add   android:gravity="center" attribute in `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
        ...
        android:gravity="center"
        ...
        />
```

Comment: Didn't work, and with this code it comes on left,top imageview.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want "...the ImageButton to be in bottm,center of ImageView"

Then you need to place them both in FrameLayout.

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#EBEBEB" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagefield"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imagefield"
            android:background="@null"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="imagebutton1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagefield"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagefield"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imagefield"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```